# How to send custom signal to kill running process with Goland?

Tags: intellij-idea, ginkgo, goland

When I run/debug `Ginkgo` test from Intellij Idea (with Go plugin installed), it does not shut down gracefully if I press "Stop" button.

[image]

`JustBeforeEach` and `AfterEach` functions do not get executed and process stops immediately. When I run test from console it gracefully shuts down if I press `Ctrl+C`. How can I make Intellij Idea/Goland to send custom signal in order to stop running process?

My `gotest` options are: `-ginkgo.v -ginkgo.progress -ginkgo.trace -ginkgo.focus=MyTest`

Answer (score 4):

GoLand sends a SIGINT then follows with a SIGKILL to terminate the process. You should make your application handle either of those signals before exiting.

Comment: If so, why I don't see output after pressing Stop button here:
`stop := make(chan os.Signal, 1)`;
`signal.Notify(stop, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGKILL)`;
`s := <-stop`;
`fmt.Printf("\nGot signal:", s)`;
I see output only if I press `Ctrl+C`

Answer (score 0):

On a Linux/Unix OS, you can use the `kill` command. For example, if you want to send an interrupt signal, you would use `kill -2 pid`.